# What's the difference between road bike disc brake wheels /cyclosross wheels?

Tags: road-bike, wheels, cyclocross, disc-brake

What's the difference between road bike disc wheels /[cyclocross disc wheels](http://www.windsailbike.com/cyclocross-wheels)?

Answer (score 2):

Cyclocoss will tend to be wider to accommodate the wider tires used in cyclocross.  And tend to be sturdier.  Are you buying the wheels for a road or cyclocross?

Comment: I added sturdier but not always the case.  Depends on the quality of the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

The real difference to look for is the axle width and connection method. A "standard" road bike has a 130mm/10mm rear axle and 100mm/9mm front axle that
both use a standard quick release.

If a set of wheels matches those dimensions and has disk brake compatible hubs, then any difference between road/cyclocross disk will only be in the various
details of the build and rim width/depth.

However, many of the newer road/cyclocross bikes with disk brakes are using different axle widths and connection methods. Often the rear hub axle is 135mm/10mm, and many CX bikes are now coming with through axle mounts. These
kinds of specs were previously only found on mountain bikes.

Many hub manufacturers ( especially on the pricy end ) now provide exchangable 
caps to allow you to switch between connection styles. But before you spring 
for those fancy carbon wheels, you should verify that the axle widths/styles
match your current bike.

Answer (score 0):

Road wheels will be more likely to be more aero with aero bladed spokes, and possibly 4 less of them. Deeper section rims are more common on road wheels than cx wheels too out on the start lines.